# json schema validator for validate key duplication node js

Tags: json, node.js, validation, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm using json schema validator for validate incoming json packet in nodejs.I'm able to check the key value is present or not, and also check whether any invalid keys are present or not.its working fine.

This is my json schema code,

```
function testLoginJsonSchema() {
}

testLoginJsonSchema.loginRequestSchema = {
            type: 'object',
            properties: {
                uname: {
                    type: 'string',
                    required: true
                },
                password: {
                    type: 'string',
                    required: true
                }
            },
            "additionalProperties": false
        };

module.exports = testLoginJsonSchema;
```

But i need to check whether the keys are duplicated or not. its not working with this code.

valid json

```
 {
        "uname":"test@manaf.com",
        "password":"validPassword"

 }
```

invalid json

```
  {
        "uname":"test@manaf.com",
        "password":"InvalidPassword",
        "password":"validPassword"

  }
```

I need to produce error message "invalid json package" for invalid json request. How it will be possible?

Answer (score 0):

JSON Schema defines constraints on *data structures* expressed by JSON documents.  So before we even think about JSON Schema, we have to figure out how to decode the JSON document, and here is our problem:

**JSON texts should not have duplicate keys**, as per [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-4) (and the earlier RFC 4627):

> The names within an object SHOULD be unique.

Behaviour when decoding this document is undefined (see the second paragraph in [Section 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-4)).  Some implementations will treat this as invalid JSON and raise a warning, most will take one of the values (first or last) and ignore others.  There is no possible input to `JSON.stringify()` that will produce duplicate keys.

If you need to check for duplicate keys in a supposedly-JSON document, this should therefore be done during the JSON-decoding step, before it even reaches a schema validator.

Comment: This does not solve the problem, only shows the cause